# MySQL Workbench 8.0.20 EER Diagram Editor display problem in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mysql-workbench

After installing MySQL Workbench 8.0.20 from its website in Ubuntu 20.04, there is a display issue in EER Diagram editor that displays the environment in part of the screen. I also test it from snapcraft. Same problem!

[image: MySQL Workbench-Screenshot]

Comment: This seems like a bug and worth reporrting to MySQL.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100367

Answer (score 2):

I had my display settings in Ubuntu set to Scale 150%.
Changing to 100% solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling on this for at least 2 hours.